# Running "go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p" results in error messages

Tags: go

I'm a beginner with golang. When trying to run "go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p" I get an error message that prevents me from being able to run tests & benchmarks.

Here is the error:

> github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/host/routed
>
> ../../libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/host/routed/routed.go:153:20: cannot use
>   rh.host.Mux() (type
>   "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/protocol".Switch) as type
>   *multistream.MultistreamMuxer in return argument: need type assertion ../../libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/host/routed/routed.go:190:5: cannot use
>   (*RoutedHost)(nil) (type *RoutedHost) as type
>   "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/host".Host in assignment:
>           *RoutedHost does not implement "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/host".Host (wrong type for Mux
>   method)
>                   have Mux() *multistream.MultistreamMuxer
>                   want Mux() "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/protocol".Switch
>
> github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/host/basic
>
> ../../libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/host/basic/basic_host.go:145:32: cannot use
>   h (type *BasicHost) as type host.Host in argument to
>   identify.NewIDService:
>           *BasicHost does not implement host.Host (wrong type for Mux method)
>                   have Mux() *multistream.MultistreamMuxer
>                   want Mux() "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/protocol".Switch
>   ../../libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/host/basic/basic_host.go:172:32: cannot use
>   h (type *BasicHost) as type host.Host in argument to
>   ping.NewPingService:
>           *BasicHost does not implement host.Host (wrong type for Mux method)
>                   have Mux() *multistream.MultistreamMuxer
>                   want Mux() "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/protocol".Switch

I don't understand why the error messages. It looks like go-libp2p does not compile. any ideas?

Comment: what's your go version?

Comment: You should probably ask the maintainers of that package

Comment: My golang ver is go1.12.2. I discovered that the dependency on libp2p in my project is for version 0.0.23 while "go get" was getting version 0.0.30. Checking if getting version 0.0.23 resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

They've been performing a [refactor](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/issues/649), which resulted in [this issue](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/issues/650) being submitted.

A solution was provided:

[image]

---